# Is the Turtle and Rabbit algorithm always O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm going to preface this with the fact that I am not completely knowledgeable on Big O Notation, so maybe my thinking about this is off.

I was randomly browsing SO when I came upon a question about detecting infinite loops in Linked Lists.  This pointed me to the algorithm [here](http://eddii.wordpress.com/2006/11/15/detecting-infinite-loop/) known as the Turtle and Rabbit.

```
class Node {
  Node next;
}

boolean isInInfiniteLoop(Node node) {
  if (node == null) {
    return false;
  }
  Node turtle = node; // slower moving node
  Node rabbit = node.next; // faster moving node
  while (rabbit != null) {
    if (rabbit.equals(turtle)) {
      // the faster moving node has caught up with the slower moving node
      return true;
    } else if (rabbit.next == null) {
      // reached the end of list
      return false;
    } else {
      turtle = turtle.next;
      rabbit = rabbit.next.next;
    }
  }
  // rabbit reached the end
  return false;
}
```

In the article he mentions that it is O(N).  From what I understand O(N) means that the speed of the algorithm grows linearly in relation to how many elements are in the list.

However, unless I am looking at things wrong, the rabbit variable is always skipping 1 node (so it's "faster") which means that it has the potential to skip over the turtle node, thus having the potential of looping around the infinite loop 1 or more times before it becomes the same node as the turtle variable, which would mean the worst-case scenario isn't O(N).

Am I missing something?  I guess an optimization might be to check if `rabbit.Next.Equals(turtle)` as well but as none of the comments point this out so I am wondering if I am missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rabbit will never jump over the turtle, because the difference between the speed is 1.

The rabbit goes in the loop first, then the turtle. As soon as the turtle goes in the loop, the difference of the rabbit and the turtle is decided, and you can consider the rabbit is behind the turtle. Then is difference is simply decreased by 1 for each step.

So the total steps will not exceed N, and thus it is O(n).

Comment: All good responses, going to mark this one only because I was mistaken and didn't realize that if both move at the same time the rabbit will never jump over the turtle.

Comment: If the total number of steps is 1 (and hence doesn't exceed N), it's not O(n). The runtime is in O(n), because in this case, the total number of steps is *at least* N/2 and at most N. Just nit-picking...  :-)

Comment: @Philip: Nitpick nitpick: Big O notation doesn't require that the number of steps is <= than the function inside the parentheses.  It only requires that for all *sufficiently big* n, the number of steps is <= *some fixed multiple* of the function.

Answer (score 3):

A little hand simulation should show you that while rabbit can skip over the turtle once, the second time around the loop, it will step on it (so to speak). (EDIT: this applies once both the rabbit and turtle are in the loop, which will happen in at most O(N) iterations.) Since O(2*N) = O(N), it's still an O(N) algorithm.

Nice algorithm, too. +1 for the link.

Comment: This only holds if they both start at the same position. In this implementation, the turtle starts at the 1st position and the rabbit already at the 2nd, so the turtle will traverse the list exactly once. The overall runtime is N (for cyclic lists) and N/2 (for non-cyclic lists) and hence in O(N).

Answer (score 2):

The Rabbit can't jump over the turtle since the turtle is moving, too. In ASCII art:

```
R _ T
    R T
        X
```

Put differently, as long as the rabbit is behind the turtle, every iteration of the loop decreases their distance by 1. Therefore, there will be an iteration where the distance becomes exactly 0.

Comment: A closer look at the implementation reveals that `rabbit.next.next` only gets executed if `rabbit.next != null`

Comment: @Ted Hopp: You're right. I have edited my answer and solemnly promise to look closer next time :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two situations:

1. There are an even number of nodes, and
2. There are an odd number of nodes.

Let's consider both.

In 1, we have this:

`T R x x`
then
`x T x R`
then
`x R T x`
then
`x x x RT`

In 2, we have this:
`T R x`
then
`R T x`
then
`x x RT`

Given the rabbit and hare can only move in max increments of two, these are the only two conditions worth noting. There's probably a proper inductive proof here, but showing the phases explains why this works even if the rabbit skips the turtle. The rabbit can only skip the turtle if he's behind the turtle, and if he's behind the turtle, either he won't skip, or he'll collide.

When the rabbit does skip the turtle, as in 1, we only need `N+1` moves of the turtle and rabbit, so `2N+2` for N being the length of the list, which is `O(N)`

Comment: In example 1, the rabbit is slacking off on his 2nd move, he only moves ahead one node.

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm becomes clearer if you instead start the rabbit and the turtle on the same node. When the turtle has moved N nodes ahead, the rabbit has moved 2N nodes ahead. If there is a cycle of length N, the turle will have returned to the starting point after N moves, and the rabbit's 2N moves will also land him on the starting node, having gone around the loop twice.